# How can I go about splicing a string to create new strings only using a part of the last string?

Tags: python, string, cpu-word, splice

So for a homework assignment, I have to slice a string like

```
GENE="ATGAGTGATGATGTA
```

And create new words (`GENE2`, `GENE3`, `GENE4`, etc...)

This is the assignment:

Starting with the word `GENE1="ATGTTGATGTG"`,
Write a Python program that creates the new words `GENE2`, `GENE3`, `GENE4` and `GENE5` such that:

- `GENE2` only contains the last two letters of `GENE1`
- `GENE3` only contains the first two letters of `GENE1`
- `GENE4` only contains the letters at positions 2,4,6,8 and 10 in `GENE1`
- `GENE5` only contains the first 3 and last 3 letters of `GENE1`

It's pretty vague, all I can think of would be to remove the letters not wanted, but that's all the professor gave us to work with.

Is this a good start?

```
GENE1 = ['A','T','G','T','T','G','A','T','G','T','G']
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want? (ie providing expected output, etc)

Comment: Could you try to clarify the question?  "GENE="ATGAGTGATGATGTA" has three parenthesis, so I'm confused about what the string is?  Is it a variable `GENE` holding the string of a DNA sequence?  or a string that contains an equal sign?

Comment: The instructions are clear. Start by at least attempting to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Im pretty new to coding, sorry.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). I think the section on strings would be quite helpful for you, as it has a good explanation on string indexing.

Comment: still pretty confused, but that was helpful ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your start should work, but you might need to use the join method of strings..

Also, You should know that just like `list`, strings (or `str`) is a container.
Which means you can slice as well as index strings, something like

```
>>> x = 'abcdefghij'
>>> x[0]
'a'
>>> x[5:]
'fghij'
>>> x[::3]
'adgj'
>>> x[-1]
'j'
```

Seems like your professor wants you to learn this and slicing and use them...

Consider reading [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html),
Or at least, these two parts on [Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (on the same page)

Comment: It so turns out that I posted the same link as grc and Benjimin, but didn't realize that even they posted the same link... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your start might work.
But you can access the chars in a string directly, eg:

```
gene1 = "ATGTTGATGTG"
gene1[0]  # this is the first letter
gene1[-1] # this is the last letter
gene1[:2] # these are the first two letters
gene1[2:] # everything after the first two letters
```

Try this in the interactive interpreter(IDLE), and then try the same with `GENE1` defined as `list`. Then you will see the difference in output.

For more information see [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) (Python Docs) (provided by @grc)